# Author's name in small caps before op. cit

Tags: biblatex

I have to convert the author names before the "op. cit." string in small caps, as with in the first citation. I'm using `\cite` as the citation command
So far, I have tried to follow the same approach of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594989/biblatex-verbose-trad2-initials-in-citations-and-full-name-in-bibliography) but without success. I don't know exactly what to inject and whether I should change the `verbose-trad1.cbx` file

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=verbose-trad1,
natbib=true,
sorting=nty,
giveninits=true,
citetracker,
isbn=false,
opcittracker=context,
labeldateparts
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% To get small caps in author name and swap given and family 
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family}
\DeclareNameFormat{given-family}{%
    \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\scshape\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
 
\begin{document}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=verbose-trad1,
natbib=true,
sorting=nty,
giveninits=true,
citetracker,
isbn=false,
opcittracker=context,
labeldateparts
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% To get small caps in author name and swap given and family 
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family}
\DeclareNameFormat{given-family}{%
    \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\scshape\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
 
\begin{document}

WHAT I GET: 
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
amet \autocite{knuth:ct:b}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}

WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE: 
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a}
ipsum \footnote{\textsc{Sigfridsson and Ryde}, op.cit.}
amet \autocite{knuth:ct:b}
ipsum \footnote{\textsc{Sigfridsson and Ryde}, op.cit.}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Footnotes 3 and 5 are wrong. Footnotes 8 and 10 are the desired outcome:

[image: Footnotes 3 and 5 are wrong. Footnotes 8 and 10 are the desired outcome]

Comment: What about the author name in footnotes 7 and 9 (i.e. with the title and not with "op. cit.")? Should that, too, be in small caps? At the moment the "and" between names is handled differently in footnotes 1 and 8/10. Should the "and" be in small caps or not?

Comment: Thank you for your help
1) Every name should be in small caps. I included only those followed by op.cit. because I want them to be changed. If the solution includes changing every name, then it should be fine. So far, I'm interest in cases 1, 8, 10. I can change the MWE accordingly. 
2) I removed the handling of "and" in the MWE for simplification. In my citation style, there is no "and". Should the solution necessarily include "and", I will handle the conjunction differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want *all* names to have small caps family names the easiest solution is to redefine `\mkbibnamefamily`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  natbib=true,
  style=verbose-trad1,
  giveninits=true,
  isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
WHAT I GET: 
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
amet \autocite{knuth:ct:b}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}

Dolor \autocite{pines}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes with names in small caps.]

If you want only the "primary name" (author or editor) associated with a work to be in all caps, it is slightly more tricky.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  natbib=true,
  style=verbose-trad1,
  giveninits=true,
  isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}%
  #1}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}%
  #1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
WHAT I GET: 
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
amet \autocite{knuth:ct:b}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}

Dolor \autocite{pines}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes with names in small caps.]

The difference between the solutions is visible in the `pines` entry (last footnote). The editor (I. Twersky) is not the primary name here and is therefore formatted differently by the two approaches.

Comment: This is exactly the solution that I was looking for. Thank you!